# Initial (mis)alignment of multiple dwgs in APS Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to place multiple dwgs into single APS Viewer scene. I place and scale the views successfully, so they are dimensionally accurate with respect to each other but for some reason even though I position all of them at {0, 0, 0} they appear misaligned like in the screenshot below.

The models have been built in AutoCAD in the same way. The origin of the model is at the bottom left corner but that seems to be irrelevant.
Does anyone has a clue why in the first place the origins of the translated files appear in different locations and secondly how to align them? I need to figure out the origin of each of the drawings to be able to calculate their final position afterwards.
[here are 3 models placed at {0,0,0}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD0kp.png)

Here's the snippet of the function I use to place the models in the scene:

```
export function loadSecondaryModel(viewer, urn) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
      let geom = doc.getRoot().search({ role: "2d", type: "geometry" });
      resolve(
        viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, geom[0], {
          keepCurrentModels: true,
          preserveView: true,
        }),
        viewer.addEventListener(
          Autodesk.Viewing.MODEL_ROOT_LOADED_EVENT,
          () => {
            let model = viewer.getAllModels()[viewer.getAllModels().length - 1];
            const secondaryModelMatrix = readModelMetadata(model);
            let tr = model.getPlacementTransform();

            tr.elements[0] = baseModelMatrix[0] / secondaryModelMatrix[0];
            tr.elements[5] = baseModelMatrix[5] / secondaryModelMatrix[5];
            tr.elements[10] = baseModelMatrix[0] / secondaryModelMatrix[0];
            tr.elements[12] = 0;
            tr.elements[13] = 0;

            model.setPlacementTransform(tr);
          }
        )
      );
    }
    function onDocumentLoadFailure(code, message, errors) {
      reject({ code, message, errors });
    }
    viewer.setLightPreset(0);
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
      "urn:" + urn,
      onDocumentLoadSuccess,
      onDocumentLoadFailure
    );
  });
}
```

I'll appreciate any hint helping me go forward.

I tried to build the models in AutoCAD in a different way but that does not seem to cause any difference. I think the origin may be modified during translation of the model but I can't work out the new one from it's properties.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `globalOffset: {x:0,y:0,z:0}` to you load options and see if that resets the origin of the drawings ?

See this example:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7

Also, are the DWG sheets wrapped in a paper space view ?

Comment: Thanks for reply! The globalOffset setting does not affect the models in any way, regardless of provided value.
Drawings are built in the model space, the layout sheet remains empty for all of them. All of them have origin (x: 0, y:0) in the bottom left corner.